# What part of speech is "that" in these two sentences:

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech, that

> 1. I believe that pigs can fly

I think here "that" is being used as a conjunction to combine the independent clause (pigs can fly) with the dependent clause (I believe)

> 2. That the boys painted the pig green annoyed the pig.

This one I'm not so sure about. "The boys painted the pig green" is an independent clause, and "annoyed the pig" is a dependent clause; but in this case "that" doesn't join them.

Any insight?

Comment: What annoyed the pig? Getting painted green by the boys. So the the second *that* clause is the subject of the independent clause, not an independent clause on its own.

Comment: Why is the subject of the IC not within the IC itself, isn't the subject of "the boys painted the pig green" boys? Also, am I right about what part of speech I am, what do you think it is?

Comment: The subject of the IC is within the IC. The subject is the noun clause *That the boys painted the pig green*; *boys* is the subject of that dependent noun clause. The initial word *that* is called a subordinator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

English has three different uses of *that*:

1. Subordinating *that*: I believe that pigs can fly.
2. Demonstrative pronoun *that*: That is not a pig.
3. Adjectival *that*: That pig cannot fly.

Both your examples are examples of the subordinating *that*.

Whether you say "It annoyed the pig that the boys painted it" or "That the boys painted the pig annoyed it" does not change the nature of the *that*. You just swap the two clauses around, is all.

And the *that* still does join them alright. Just try dropping it to see that it does.